# Kotlin - Make extension function accessible in whole project

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

I have this extension function in a class:

```
fun Double.round2() : Double {
   return Math.round((this) * 100.0) / 100.0
}
```

I want to reuse this function in another class without the need to duplicate the code. How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Your function should be defined at the top level. It will be automatically visible anywhere from the same package, and from other packages with the help of an `import` statement.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a problem, cause you you always have to organize your project taking in account this limitation.

Comment: Which limitation? There are no limitations involved here, just additional features which you should embrace.